# Simple ISBN Bookup for Amazon

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, isbn

I'm trying to find a simple way to look up book titles by ISBN in Amazon. I'm assisting my kid's school in doing a simple inventory. A good number of the books in my test set aren't found using other sources (tried Google, WorldCat and ISBN DB).

Example ISBN: 0153527692

I've read about the "Product Advertising API" but this seems like overkill- is there anything more basic I'm missing?

If I do a search via the Amazon site it comes up which is why I'm thinking Amazon- I'm open to other ideas as well...

Comment: how about this: http://www.isbnsearch.org/isbn/0153527692 ? So it will be easier to program with the ISBN code.

Comment: you can look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the exact same problem. Newer editions of books are not returned by the APIs you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple ways to fetch book information from an ISBN number.

You can use the following services:

- Amazon API (LookupbyISBN)
- Google Books API
- ISBNdb API
- [Worldcat Search API](http://xisbn.worldcat.org/xisbnadmin/doc/api.htm)

Here you can find [an example](http://agregationchimie.free.fr/book_isbn.php) (in French) with source code in PHP.

Hope this helps,

GuGuss

Comment: I tried the worldcat api and got a strange result.  In the browser it works perfectly but when I query using curl or wget with exactly the same URL I don't get any metadata back.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to quote the url and it had an asterisk in it so the shell was trying to expand it.  It looks like Worldcat is the way to go as they allow a thousand look ups per day for nothing.